# Bad scaling versus collinearity

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix, linear-solver, scaling

I was trying to solve a linear system:

$$
\mathbf{A}\mathbf{x} = \mathbf{y}
$$

but the conditioning number was quite bad (around $10^{17}$).
I thought that the system was singular, but after scaling the 
system using the diagonal matrix:

$$
\mathbf{D_{ii}} = 1/\sqrt{\mathbf{A_{ii}}}
$$

and the fact:

$$
\mathbf{A}^{-1} = \mathbf{D} (\mathbf{D}\mathbf{A}\mathbf{D})^{-1}\mathbf{D}.
$$

The conditioning number of $\mathbf{D}\mathbf{A}\mathbf{D}$ is around $10^3$!
Does this imply that the system was just badly scaled and that there is no
collinearity?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, that's what it means.  This is usually illustrated with $A$ a diagonal matrix having both large and small entries.  Clearly such a matrix can be accurately inverted, but a simple measure of condition number being ratio of largest eigenvalue to smallest (in this case, largest diagonal entry to smallest) would easily give a high value.